# Forcing a DROP in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How can I force DROP a TEMP TABLE? I have a web app that is using temp tables, but I keep running into this error:

```
PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  cannot DROP TABLE "t" because it is being used by active queries in this session
```

I see there is a RESTRICT option on DROP, but is there a way to not restrict? Or is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Well, the message "*because it is being used by active queries in this session*" is pretty clear: make sure you are no longer using that table. If I had to guess: you started a transaction using that table, but never committed that transaction and those sessions are not "idle in transaction" - rather then just "idle"

Comment: Read the error message: `it is being used by active queries in this session` - perhaps find out what's using it and kill it before attempting to drop it?

Comment: There is a cursor that is using it, but the fact that it is being created again means it is no longer necessary. If there is a way to force drop it that seems like the easiest solution

Comment: Would it be better practice to use CTE instead of temp table for this application?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect whether or not any transaction is using the table by issuing:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

When you find queries that probably are `idle in transaction` or `active` and involve table `t` then you can force termination of that query or the client (this issues `ROLLBACK`) which issues the query itself by identifying it with `pid` which is returned from the above query:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(${pid here}); -- cancel query
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(${pid here}); -- terminate connection
```

Just replace `${pid here}` with the `pid` from querying stats activity view.

Or you could even do it in some crazy fashion (though I rather recommend doing it manually) like that:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE query ~* ' t'
  AND pid <> pg_backend_pid(); -- prevent killing "yourself" ;-)
```

**Above solution is unsafe considering your table name and should never be used in production!** This could match many queries not involving the table `t`!

Comment: You can also use `pg_locks` to determine exactly which sessions are accessing the table or have accessed it.